# What's wrong with my mongo query(meteor)?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm using meteor. I'm have 1 user in database and one additional field in 'profile' -> accepted. I'm checked value of 'accepted' by db.users.find() and value is true.
So, my query is(returns 0):

```
//index.js
fooFunc: function(){return Meteor.users.find({accepted: true}, {fields:{'profile': 1}}).count();}
```

This query returns 1:

```
//index.js
fooFunc: function(){return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields:{'profile': 1}}).count();}
```

Why first query returns 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query searches for the number of users with the `accepted` field at the value `true`. But your users don't have an `accepted` field. They have `profile.accepted`.

Thus,

```
Meteor.users.find({'profile.accepted' : true}, 
  {fields:{'profile': 1}}).count();
```